# TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: node.js, seneca

### Error

> - Seneca Fatal Error
>        ==================
>
>   Message: seneca: Action cmd:signup,role:api failed: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined.
>
>   Code: act_execute
>
>   Details: { message: 'Cannot read property \'replace\' of undefined',
>          pattern: 'cmd:signup,role:api',
>          fn: [Function: signup],
>          cb: [Function],
>          instance: 'Seneca/pr061njfdnng/1504005334341/1/3.2.2/-',
>          'orig$':
>           TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
>               at /usr/src/app/services/common.js:22:24
>               at Array.forEach (native)
>               at module.exports (/usr/src/app/services/common.js:20:13)
>               at Seneca.signup (/usr/src/app/services/api.js:117:17)
>               at execute_action (/usr/src/app/node_modules/seneca/seneca.js:1060:20)
>               at Object.act_fn [as fn] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/seneca/seneca.js:1013:11)
>               at Immediate.processor (/usr/src/app/node_modules/gate-executor/gate-executor.js:136:14)
>               at runCallback (timers.js:781:20)
>               at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:743:5)
>               at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:714:5),
>          'message$': 'Cannot read property \'replace\' of undefined',
>          plugin: {} }
>
>   Stack:
>            at /usr/src/app/services/common.js:22:24
>            at Array.forEach (native)
>            at module.exports (/usr/src/app/services/common.js:20:13)
>            at Seneca.signup (/usr/src/app/services/api.js:117:17)
>            at execute_action (/usr/src/app/node_modules/seneca/seneca.js:1060:20)
>            at Object.act_fn [as fn] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/seneca/seneca.js:1013:11)
>            at Immediate.processor (/usr/src/app/node_modules/gate-executor/gate-executor.js:136:14)
>            at runCallback (timers.js:781:20)
>            at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:743:5)
>            at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:714:5)

### Code

```
if(queryString.indexOf('?') > -1){
        queryString = queryString.split('?')[1];
      }
      var pairs = queryString.split('&');

      pairs.forEach(function(pair) {
        pair = pair.split('=');      
        var s = pair[1].replace(/\+/g," ");
        //console.log('s', s);
        //console.log('pair[1]', pair[1]);
        var sfinal = decodeURIComponent(s || '');
        //console.log('sfinal', sfinal);

        result[pair[0]] = sfinal;
      });
      //done( null, result )
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is no '=' in pair, the array returned will have a single element and index 1 will returned undefined. Maybe you should check that.

Answer (score 1):

replace your code

```
var s = pair[1].replace(/\+/g," ");
```

to

```
var s = (!isNaN(pair[1])) ? pair[1].replace(/\+/g," ") : null;
```

Comment: Thanks bro I will try this and give u the feedback